# Gitlab CI multiple branches

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two branches: ***master*** and ***test***. When I push to the master branch, my code is deployed to the first server by gitlab-ci. I want to deploy to a different server whenever I push to the test branch. Is this possible using Gitlab CI?

- master - 10.10.10.1
- test - 10.10.10.2

My ***gitlab-ci.yml***:

```
maven_build:
script: 
    - mvn install
    - /opt/payara41/bin/./asadmin --passwordfile /home/asadminpass --user admin undeploy myApplication-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT
    - sudo /etc/init.d/glassfish restart
    - /opt/payara41/bin/./asadmin --passwordfile /home/asadminpass --host localhost --user admin deploy --force /home/gitlab-runner/builds/10b25461/0/myapp/myAppPrototype/myApp-ear/target/myApplication-SNAPSHOT.ear

only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 13):

You're on the right track with `only:`.

Simply create two different steps, one with `only: master` and one with `only: test`.
Change the `script:` to deploy to a different server.

```
deploy_master:
  script: 
    - <script to deploy to master server>
  only:
    - master

deploy_test:
  script: 
    - <script to deploy to test server>
  only:
    - test
```

Comment: How to do this? This is two diffrent linux server (not application server). From where the second gitlab- runner knows whith branch they should deploy?

Comment: @dbrekelmans, is this possible on gitlab.com or only if you have your own servers?

Answer (score 3):

```
only
 - dev
 - staging
 - master
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking you can do the following
for master

```
Pushing changes:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
```

for test

```
Pushing changes:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "test"
```

this will define  the when based on your branch.

As for the how to deploy

in your script section you can add for master

```
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

for test

```
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_TEST
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_TEST
    - aws configure set region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION_TEST
```

add all the variable in Settings->CICD ->Variables